# Default value of state is not updated between renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Consider following example. Im  calling a fetching function in parent from child.

The request finishes, Im passing the data from async request to my `Child` as `items` prop. Im setting it as a default value for `useState` - `React.useState(items);`.

Expected behavior: request finishes, `items` is updated, `Child` gets new props, its re-rendered and the default value in `useState` is updated. So the `a` variable hold the proper object.

Actual behavior: the default value in `useState` is not updated between renders. Why?

```js
const Child = ({ fn, items }) => {
  const [a, b] = React.useState(items);
  console.log(a, items); // a is null but items is an object
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fn();
  }, []);

  return JSON.stringify(a);
}

const App = () => {
  const [stateOne, setStateOne] = React.useState(null);

  const fn = () => {
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        setStateOne(json);
      });
    }
    
  console.log(stateOne)
  return <Child fn={fn} items={stateOne} />;
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: `fetch()` is asynchronous.  `console()` is not.  So, `fetch();console.log(fetchresults);`, is almost always empty, unless your network is FTL.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger Thanks but thats not the case in this example.

Comment: correct the naming convention `const [a, setA] = React.useState(items);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value is intentionally only used when the component mounts. That's what's meant by "default". After that, the only way to change the state is by calling the state-setter function (`b` in your code).

It's rare that you need to copy a prop into state, so the likely fix is to just delete the state entirely, and use the prop.

```
const Child = ({ fn, items }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fn();
  }, []);

  return JSON.stringify(items);
}
```

If you do need to have state for some reason, first consider if you can move that state up to the parent and thus eliminate this issue. If for some reason you can't do that either, then you'll need to have the child implement logic which calls the state setter `b` when you want it to be called. For example:

```
const Child = ({ fn, items }) => {
  const [a, b] = React.useState(items);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    b(items);
  }, [items]);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fn();
  }, []);

  return JSON.stringify(a);
}
```

Comment: So once component is mounted, it will never change, unless the component is unmounted and mounted again, yes?

Comment: Yes, the default value will be used exactly once, when the component mounts. If you unmount and remount, then you get a new element which will use its default value (which might be different from what the old element had).

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood what it means to have a "default value" in the case of React hooks. It's not so much a "default value" as an "initial value".

Consider the following code:

```
let n = Math.random();
const [myN, setMyN] = useState(n);

console.log(n) // This number will always be the same between renders
```

In your case, the initial value is `null`. It will **never** change unless if you call the setter for it.

If you're looking to pass down a prop, don't mix it into state.